# undefined method `user_session_path' using devise in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am developing a rails engine.

This is an excerpt from my routes file:

```
devise_for :users, class_name: "Subscribem::User", controllers: { sessions: 'devise/sessions', passwords: 'devise/passwords', registrations: 'devise/registrations' }
```

These are my session routes:

```
    new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
```

When I use any link like this:

```
= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path
```

Then I retrieve the "undefined method `user_session_path'" error. My engine also has isolated namespaces and I can't figure out the problem.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should post the full error - it's likely coming somewhere from the code on your signin page.

Comment: where are you using this link? in the engine?

Comment: restart your server yet after installing devise?

Comment: @Trip The server was restarted of course :)

Comment: @apneadiving I am using the link in the engine itself.

It seems that the problem is coming from the devise views. The login form of devise is using the user_session_path method post... but the user_session_path should be used as subscribem.user_session_path...
Any ideas?

Comment: The error is coming from: session_path(resource_name) which is in the sessions/new.html.erb devise view...

Comment: The docs are here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine

Comment: I needed to add this line to the initializers/devise.rb

config.router_name = :subscribem

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks @Boti for the solution. Note that if you mounted your engine using an alias, you need to use that alias in `config.router_name = :my_engine`.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me in a devise is inside of the mountable engine(rails 6.0.3.1).
I was trying to

```
user_session_path
```

Instead it should've been

```
EngineName::Engine.routes.url_helpers.user_session_path
```